# Property 'previousPageIndex' does not exist on type 'MatPaginator'

Tags: angular, angular-material

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm trying to store previousPageIndex in session storage but I've got the following message

```
Property 'previousPageIndex' does not exist on type 'MatPaginator'.
```

. I'm working with Angular 7.0, and length, and the rest of the properties are stored without any issues,

```
 readPaginator(): void {
    console.log("Reading paginator");
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('paginator')) {
      const pageStored: PageEvent  = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('paginator'));
      this.dataSource.paginator.length = pageStored.length;
      this.dataSource.paginator.pageSize = pageStored.pageSize;
      this.dataSource.paginator.pageIndex = pageStored.pageIndex;
      this.dataSource.paginator.previousPageIndex = pageStored.previousPageIndex;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you made a mistake with types here.
`previousPageIndex` is a property of an event [PageEvent](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#PageEvent).
`Paginator` itself does not know what this is, hence the error message.
Just do not set `previousPageIndex` or change
`const pageStored: PageEvent`
to
 `const paginator: MatPaginator`.
API is described [here](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/api#MatPaginator).